# Create a list of sets of atoms

Tags: python, set

Say I have an array of atoms like this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

(the length may be any)

And I want to create a list of sets that can be made with them:

```
[  
    ['a'], ['b'], ['c'],  
    ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'c'],  
    ['a', 'b', 'c']  
]
```

Is it possible to do it easily in python?

Maybe it's very easy to do, but I'm not getting it myself.
Thank you.

Comment: You missed `['b','c']`, by the way. ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That sounds to me like [`powerset`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

Comment: If you start from `1`, losing the empty tuple

Comment: Nailed it. Take my upvotes. (`itertools`: is there *anything* it can't do?)

Answer (score 4):

Easy. Use `itertools.combinations()`:

```
from itertools import combinations

atom = list('abc')

combs = [i for j in range(1, len(atom) + 1) for i in combinations(atom, j)]
```

which yields:

```
[('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
from itertools import product
masks = [p for p in product([0, 1], repeat=len(data))]
combs = [[x for i, x in enumerate(data) if mask[i]] for mask in masks]
```